# Change storefront search field placeholder

Tags: search, woocommerce, placeholder, storefront

and thanks in advance.
NOTE: NSFW site, maybe some hot images from eBooks covers, no nude but adult romance covers.

ok,

I have WP+storefront+bookshop child theme, I want to change the placeholder “Search products…”within search field (#woocommerce-product-search-field-0). No matter what I try, it seems not to affect placeholder.

I could change search width, alignment, text and border color BUT not placeholder…
here the code so far

```
> /*Align Search Bar and make text and border pink #fe00a1*/
> #woocommerce-product-search-field-0 { display:inline-block; width:100%; color: #fe00a1; border: solid 1px #fe00a1; }
```

I also tried several PHP snippets, the best one that allowed me to change almost any text within woocommerce is this GETTEXT filter

```
> function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) { switch
> ( $translated_text ) { case ‘Search products…’ : $translated_text =
> __( ‘Search for contemporary romance books, series ot authors…’, ‘woocommerce’ ); break; } return $translated_text; } add_filter(
> ‘gettext’, ‘my_text_strings’, 20, 3 );
```

but..yes, you guessed, it didn´t work.

How can I replace the locked, hidden, or whatever has “Search products” with “Search for contemporary romance books, series or authors…”?? CSS, PHP, some tip?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the solution, thank to @jobthomas from [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/)

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3);

    function my_text_strings( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
      $translated = str_ireplace( 'Search products', 'Search for contemporary books &#044; series or authors', $translated );
      return $translated;
    }
```